Is there a single ended input single ended output amplifier integrated circuit?
Yes, nowadays everything is used as operational amplifiers with differential input single ended output , or fully differential output  (common mode rejection ratio is high, common mode noise is canceled.) These can also be used as single ended. However, the question I'm curious about is this. I've worked with amplifiers that contain discrete single ended input and single ended output before. So are there integrated circuits with single-ended inputs and single-ended outputs (past or present)?
A finding: The differential input advantage was discovered with vacuum tubes, so when designing the IC, differential input amplifiers, which already existed and had known advantages, were designed instead of single-ended input.

Wouldn't grounding one of the differential inputs give you what you want? But you might search for "transimpedance amplifiers" to see if there's anything that meets your definitions.

Thanks for feedback , I know I can use differential input opmaps as single ended input, this is more about whether single ended input amplifier ICs exist in history or today rather than causality,

The LT1010 is single-ended input.

Many RF amplifiers are single-ended input, not differential.  Here is one example from NXP:


Here is another example from Maxim (now owned by Analog Devices):-


